# Pre loader gif only working on medium resolutions

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, z-index

I'm using the preloader of [this tutorial -the first part-](https://smallenvelop.com/display-loading-icon-page-loads-completely/), and it's pretty cool and easy to implement. But it's only working on medium sized resolutions (extending or decreasing the resolution from medium borders, it dissapears like behind everything else).
By medium resolution I mean according to the Bootrap grid sizes:

```
   The Grid Sizes 
.col-xs-$   Extra Small Phones Less than 768px
.col-sm-$   Small Devices   Tablets 768px and Up
.col-md-$   Medium Devices  Desktops 992px and Up
.col-lg-$   Large Devices   Large Desktops 1200px and Up
```

Seems like the z-index gets totally overlapped, I even checked every z-index in the styles I use and they are all below the "99999" I set to this .se-pre-con div.
  Any idea on how to fix this issue or what to look for? I'm really bad at front-end. Sorry if this is pretty basic but sounds like I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the beloved problem's root cause. The code in the bootstrap.css I added for the loader was trapped inside the devils trap:

```
 @media (min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 992px) {
```

So, since my style was in there, it was only vissible on those resolution width.